# Is there a way to use ssh remotely without configure the firewall?

Tags: ssh

Is there an application that works like TeamViewer but only works for SSH?

I'm configuring a server, and want to place it anywhere but still be able to access ith with putty. Is there a service or application I can use to access it? Much a like TeamViewer, but I don't want the desktop, only SSH

Comment: Why you need to configure firewall to access this server?

Comment: I don't know what a teamviewer is. What are you trying to achieve? How is what you want different from simply running an SSH server? Obviously you'll have to allow incoming SSH connections if you want to connect over SSH.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to have a server with SSH enabled somewhere on the internet and to use SSH port-forwarding to have the remote server accessible irrespective of IP or (incoming) firewall. `autossh` will monitor and restart an SSH session. It can be started from rc.local or from a proper init script.

SSH keys should be set up and the server on the internet need to have port forwarding enabled.

An example: `autossh -M20000 -f -N -R2222:localhost:22 username-for-server@server-on-internet` should make the server running the command accessible with `ssh -p 2222 myuser@server-on-internet`

The obvious disadvantage is that you need your own server on the internet. (It can be seen as an advantage in that you don't pass your data through a third-party)

This has some examples on setting it to start on boot: (for Ubuntu)
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/automatically-restart-ssh-sessions-and-tunnels-using-autossh.html

Comment: The 20000 and 2222 would need to be changed if additional servers use the name internet server.

Comment: Additional note: Managing the `.known_hosts` file (or getting PuTTY to check for different keys on different ports would probably be annoying...)

Answer (score 0):

You can email new IP address after server reboot ;)

More info here: [Support trick: Automatically receive the IP addresses of remote computers](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/support-trick-automatically-receive-the-ip-addresses-of-remote-computers/)

But I will prefer service like [dyndns](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Internet/Protocols/DNS/Service_Providers/Dynamic_DNS/) for achieving this.

Comment: That is quite a brilliant trick, but firewalls / NAT might still cause problems... (A DynDNS-type service would also work for getting the IP)

Comment: Yes, my second tip was for dyndns service, which is much easier :)